# Spring Data JPA + H2 embedded persistence : CrudRepository.save saves only to memory on restart no longer see the changes

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

I have a simple Spring Data JPA setup with h2 embedded persistence. I created a bunch of entities & set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` since i am only intending to use it as a light weight embedded persistence mechanism & do not need/want to define the schema manually or worry about schema migration, etc (since this data is not going to be migrated).

Now when i do a `CrudRepository.save` it works perfectly and subsequent `find` calls return the saved entities. I am also able to see these in the hibernate auto created tables from the H2 console aswell.

However the moment i restart the service strangely some of the changes are gone. When i dig a little i see that this happens only with entities that are in a `@OneToMany` relationship with the enclosing 'parent' entity.

For example in the below this issue happens only with `IpInterface` entities, where when i add another `IpInterface` entity and save from `enclosingContainerRepository.save()`. I see it all works fine & the new `IpInterface` is seen in the table on the console aswell. But the moment i restart the service the new `IpInterface` entity is gone. But if i add a new `EnclosingContainer` entity that is persisted properly across service restarts.

I also tried using `JpaRepository` with its `saveAndFlush` with the same result.

Does any one know why this is happening?

```
public interface EnclosingContainerRepository extends CrudRepository<EnclosingContainer, String> {
...
...
}

@Entity
public class EnclosingContainer implements Serializable {
  ...
    ...
    @Id
    private String ipAddress;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private SomeDTO someDTO;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<SomePort> somePorts;
  ...
  ...
}

@Entity
public class SomePort implements Serializable {
  ...
  ...
  @Id
  private String macAddress;

  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
  private List<IpInterface> ipInterfaces;
  ...
  ...
}

@Entity
public class IpInterface implements Serializable {
  ...
  ...
  @Id
  private String ipAddress;
  ...
  ...
}
```

Log on service startup (i insert some test entities on startup whose SQL log i skip since its done post application startup from the `ApplicationReadyEvent` event handler):

```
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:06.122 [SpringContextShutdownHook] org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean   - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:06.125 [SpringContextShutdownHook] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:06.125 [SpringContextShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource   - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:06.132 [SpringContextShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource   - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
/usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca
/usr/lib/jvm/zulu8-ca/bin/java -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:InitialRAMPercentage=80.0 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --port=9886
19:40:54,095 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Will scan for changes in [file:////*****/conf/logback-spring.xml] 
19:40:54,095 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeTask scanning period to 30 seconds
19:40:54,097 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ContextNameAction - Setting logger context name as [embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service]
19:40:54,097 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
19:40:54,097 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
19:40:54,098 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
19:40:54,099 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender]
19:40:54,102 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [DCM-COMMON-FILE-APPENDER]
19:40:54,108 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1610702581 - setting totalSizeCap to 1 GB
19:40:54,110 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1610702581 - Archive files will be limited to [100 MB] each.
19:40:54,112 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1610702581 - Will use gz compression
19:40:54,114 |-INFO in c.q.l.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy@1610702581 - Will use the pattern /*****/logs/embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log for the active file
19:40:54,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1356d4d4 - The date pattern is 'yyyy-MM-dd' from file name pattern '/*****/logs/embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log.gz'.
19:40:54,116 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1356d4d4 - Roll-over at midnight.
19:40:54,118 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP@1356d4d4 - Setting initial period to Sun Nov 22 19:40:06 GMT 2020
19:40:54,121 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
19:40:54,123 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[DCM-COMMON-FILE-APPENDER] - Active log file name: /*****/logs/embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service.log
19:40:54,123 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[DCM-COMMON-FILE-APPENDER] - File property is set to [/*****/logs/embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service.log]
19:40:54,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to INFO
19:40:54,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@6c779568 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
19:40:54,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[ROOT]
19:40:54,124 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [DCM-COMMON-FILE-APPENDER] to Logger[ROOT]
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.*****] to INFO
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@6c779568 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[com.*****] onto the JUL framework
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [com.*****] to false
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[com.*****]
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [DCM-COMMON-FILE-APPENDER] to Logger[com.*****]
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache] to WARN
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@6c779568 - Propagating WARN level on Logger[org.apache] onto the JUL framework
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting additivity of logger [org.apache] to false
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache]
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [DCM-COMMON-FILE-APPENDER] to Logger[org.apache]
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
19:40:54,125 |-INFO in org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.SpringBootJoranConfigurator@2525ff7e - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point
19:40:54,152 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@6c779568 - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[org.hibernate.SQL] onto the JUL framework
19:40:54,152 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@6c779568 - Propagating TRACE level on Logger[org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] onto the JUL framework
19:40:54,152 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@6c779568 - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate] onto the JUL framework
19:40:54,153 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@6c779568 - Propagating TRACE level on Logger[org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils] onto the JUL framework
19:40:54,153 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@6c779568 - Propagating INFO level on Logger[springfox.documentation] onto the JUL framework

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.4.RELEASE)

embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:54.241 [background-preinit] org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version   - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.5.Final
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:54.291 [main] com.*****.dcm.Application - Starting Application on fec4e3863bb1 with PID 1 (/BOOT-INF/lib/*****-service-base-1.0.0.jar started by root in /)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:54.292 [main] com.*****.dcm.Application - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:55.506 [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate    - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFERRED mode.
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:55.743 [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate    - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 220ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:56.581 [main] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9886 (http)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:56.680 [main] org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext   - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2313 ms
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:56.841 [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource    - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:57.112 [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource    - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:57.138 [main] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration  - H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:file:/*****/data/embeddeddb'
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:57.470 [main] org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:57.545 [task-1] org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper   - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:57.656 [task-1] org.hibernate.Version   - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.21.Final
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [WARN ] 19:40:57.702 [main] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration   - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:57.895 [task-1] org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version    - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [WARN ] 19:40:58.039 [main] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration - Cannot find template location: classpath:/templates/ (please add some templates, check your Mustache configuration, or set spring.mustache.check-template-location=false)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:58.087 [task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect   - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.736 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table some_port_ip_interfaces 
       drop constraint if exists UK_35lp2m9yn4lwhxr1wg13yeyl7
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.739 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table some_port_ip_interfaces 
       add constraint UK_35lp2m9yn4lwhxr1wg13yeyl7 unique (ip_interfaces_ip_address)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.741 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table some_port_ip_routes 
       drop constraint if exists UK_1xj488s5dl977k0691s4fd2qx
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.741 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table some_port_ip_routes 
       add constraint UK_1xj488s5dl977k0691s4fd2qx unique (ip_routes_ip_address)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.742 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_cards 
       drop constraint if exists UK_7d9qcums0vny0xs332x7t4qyy
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.743 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_cards 
       add constraint UK_7d9qcums0vny0xs332x7t4qyy unique (cards_serial_number)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.744 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_frus 
       drop constraint if exists UK_eu4kr3fyg4mf6thowl9noyrhm
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.744 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_frus 
       add constraint UK_eu4kr3fyg4mf6thowl9noyrhm unique (frus_serial_number)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.745 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_some_ports 
       drop constraint if exists UK_lldpgafxjyc2gldj1unsbmx9d
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.746 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_some_ports 
       add constraint UK_lldpgafxjyc2gldj1unsbmx9d unique (some_ports_mac_address)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.748 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_sensors 
       drop constraint if exists UK_5aj4uiaxj26tn8k4gullpjqug
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.748 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_sensors 
       add constraint UK_5aj4uiaxj26tn8k4gullpjqug unique (sensors_sensor_id)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.749 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_switch_ports 
       drop constraint if exists UK_qwm9mj7t8vbt1qn748eakgh0n
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.750 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_switch_ports 
       add constraint UK_qwm9mj7t8vbt1qn748eakgh0n unique (switch_ports_wwn)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.751 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_virtual_fcoe_ports 
       drop constraint if exists UK_32fnh9qvsxjk1yf2iw7cu48ek
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.751 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_virtual_fcoe_ports 
       add constraint UK_32fnh9qvsxjk1yf2iw7cu48ek unique (virtual_fcoe_ports_port_wwn)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.752 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_virtual_switches 
       drop constraint if exists UK_awii5etqk1qpq70kxu2jitt1j
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:40:59.752 [task-1] org.hibernate.SQL   - 
    
    alter table enclosing_container_virtual_switches 
       add constraint UK_awii5etqk1qpq70kxu2jitt1j unique (virtual_switches_wwn)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:59.791 [task-1] org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:59.800 [task-1] org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean  - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:59.897 [main] org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.EndpointLinksResolver   - Exposing 13 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:59.961 [main] org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  - Tomcat started on port(s): 9886 (http) with context path '/embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service'
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:40:59.962 [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener   - Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:41:00.445 [main] org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener   - Spring Data repositories initialized!
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [INFO ] 19:41:00.461 [main] com.*****.dcm.Application - Started Application in 6.711 seconds (JVM running for 7.5)
embedded-lightweight-persistence-sample-service - [DEBUG] 19:41:00.551 [main] org.hibernate.SQL - 
....
....
```

UPDATE (11/22/2020) :
Guys sorry for the bother, i figured the cause which was a stupid thing i was doing where in i was updating the parent entity with the same id that i was testing the edit operations with on app startup (missed removing post my initial verification) which was resulting in the appearance of the change not persisting across reboots. When i removed it, it worked like a breeze.

Thanks to every one who looked at. Thanks @Shawrup in particular for the helpful note on checking what happens on start up, that helped me realize the error i was doing.

Comment: can you enable hibernate show-sql and share the ddl at startup ?

Comment: Sorry hit post length limitation...trimmed to just up to `Started Application`

Comment: Not sure why i see those alter table statements..since its the same service just being restarted and hibernate should not find any difference in the schema to adjust...

Comment: @Shawrup Thank you so much once again for the time!...i realized the issue was because of my test code updating the same entity that i was testing the edit operations with on startup making it look like changes do not persist across reboots...even though its a stupid mistake on my part due to oversight (apologize for it) it was your suggestion  to look at the startup & log that helped me see the cause. Please mark it as answer so i can accept it..thanks once again!

Comment: @Shawrup thanks again. Could you please also help share your thoughts on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64998743/why-does-jpa-onetoone-even-onetomany-have-its-orphanremoval-default-to-false) question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to answer & close this one.

It turns out, the issue was because of my test code updating the same entity that i was testing the edit operations with on startup making it look like changes do not persist across reboots, when in fact they did.

Thanks to @Shawrup for helping me see the issue by looking at the startup logs.

Thanks